# Downloading file on ESP32 using WiFiClient.client.read() fails -- "Task watchdog" error

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

I'm testing code downloading large files (approx 1mb OTA binary file) from a server

The error happens midway through the download:

```
-> E (15787) task_wdt: Task watchdog got triggered. The following tasks did not reset the watchdog in time:
-> E (15787) task_wdt:  - async_tcp (CPU 0/1)
-> E (15787) task_wdt: Tasks currently running:
-> E (15787) task_wdt: CPU 0: IDLE0
-> E (15787) task_wdt: CPU 1: IDLE1
-> E (15787) task_wdt: Aborting.
-> abort() was called at PC 0x400e16af on core 0
```

My current understanding based on [this ESP32 github link](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/922), is that the  download process is blocking the ESP from performing necessary background functions.

The failure happens (in the code below) during a `while()` loop that runs a `client.read()` to fetch the file from a server.

I tried testing `delay()` and `vTaskDelay()` to see if they might help.  Wasn't sure if that frees things up or just further adds to any task blocking.  Neither helped.  (and I think [they're the same function](https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=2379) anyway, correct?)

I'm not 100% sure blocking is even the issue.  Monitoring the download using a `Serial.println(thisClient.available())` showed the *bytes remaining* going from about 7k to around 5k before jumping backup to 7k -- and doing that repeatedly.  That suggests a possible a server issue. BUT that same server, downloading the same file to a JS-coded ajax request works just fine.

The test code below is adapted from an [Espressif OTA Example](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/Update/examples/AWS_S3_OTA_Update/AWS_S3_OTA_Update.ino).
I'm still new to C++, so forgive the use of String over char arrays.  Having trouble working with those chars.

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <Update.h>
#include "AsyncJson.h"
#include "ArduinoJson.h"

AsyncWebServer EspServer(80);

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);

    const char* ClientSsid = "***";
    const char* ClientPwd = "***";
    Serial.print("Connecting to LAN ");
    WiFi.begin(ClientSsid, ClientPwd);
    int CreepConnect;
    CreepConnect=0;
    while (WiFi.status()!=WL_CONNECTED && CreepConnect<30){
        delay(250);
        Serial.print(".");
        CreepConnect++;
    }
    Serial.println(" on SSID " + WiFi.SSID() + " at " + String(WiFi.localIP()));

    EspServer.on("*", HTTP_POST, [](AsyncWebServerRequest * Req){
        AsyncWebParameter* keyVal=Req->getParam(0);
        String key=keyVal->name();
        String val=keyVal->value();
        if(key=="req" && val=="execOTA"){
            Serial.println("Updating...");
            Req->send(200, "text/plain", "Updating...");
            //EspServer.end(); //Tested disabling server
            execOTA();
        }else{
            Serial.println("Request ignored");
            Req->send(200, "text/plain", "Request ignored");
        }
    });
    EspServer.begin();
    //execOTA();  This does work.  It only fails under the callback above.
}

String execOTA(){
    WiFiClient thisClient;
    IPAddress thisHost(192, 168, 1, 10);
    char thisPath[]="/testBigFile.ino.esp32.bin"; //Big = about 800k OTA bin file
    String thisPart, theseHeaders, thisBody;
    if(!thisClient.connect(thisHost, 8465)){
        Serial.println("Connection Failed");
        return "{\"Error\":\"Connection Failed\"}";
    }
    Serial.println(thisPath);
    Serial.println(String(thisPath));
    Serial.println("Connection succeeded");
    Serial.print("thisClient.available(): ");
    Serial.println(thisClient.available());
    String thisReq=String("GET ") + String(thisPath) + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
        "Host: 192.168.1.10:8465\r\n" +
        "Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n" +
        "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
    Serial.println("thisReq: " + thisReq);
    thisClient.print(thisReq);
    unsigned long timeout = millis();
    while(thisClient.available()==0) {
        if(millis()-timeout > 5000){
            Serial.println("Client timed out");
            thisClient.stop();
            Serial.println("Client timed out");
            return "{\"Error\":\"Client timed out\"}";

        }
    }
    Serial.println("Headers Begin");
    thisPart="Header";
    while(thisClient.available()){
        Serial.println(thisClient.available());
        if(thisPart=="Header"){
            String thisLine=thisClient.readStringUntil('\n');
            theseHeaders.concat(thisLine);
            thisLine.trim();
            if(!thisLine.length()){
                Serial.println("Headers Complete:\n" + theseHeaders + "\n------\n");
                thisPart="Body";
            }
        }else{ //*** Task Watchdog Error happens in this block, after about 50 successful character reads with delay ***
            char thisChar=thisClient.read();
            thisBody.concat(thisChar);
            //delay(10); //Tested at various durations to see if it adds to or frees up blocking.  It seems to add further blocking?
            //vTaskDelay(15); //Also tested, at various durations.
        }
    }
    Serial.println("Body Complete");
    thisClient.stop();
    return "{\"Headers\":\"" + theseHeaders + "\",\"Body\":\"" + thisBody + "\"}";
}

String getHeaderValue(String header, String headerName){
    return header.substring(strlen(headerName.c_str()));
}
```

Comment: Where is this code running? Inside `loop()`? Or in a callback? The error you quoted mentions async_tcp - are you using the EasyAsyncTCP library?

Comment: Look at this example and work from there on: https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/ArduinoOTA/examples/BasicOTA/BasicOTA.ino  If you want to rewrite the functionality of the lib look into it and copy what you need

Comment: romkey: I edited the OP to answer your questions, including the full code.  Summarized: the code is running inside callback.  The libraries are <WiFi.h>,  <Update.h>, "AsyncJson.h", "ArduinoJson.h"  The idea is to accommodate curl/ajax requests along the lines of `curl -d 'req=execOTA'` The execOTA function runs just fine outside the callback, if you run it on bootup. It only fails when wrapped in the callback.

Comment: Codebreaker007: Thanks for that.  Looking into it.

Comment: RE ArduinoOTA -- so far haven't been able to see how it would be used to retrieve an update from a remote server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing too much in the HTTP callback. While the callback is running, the watchdog timer can't be reset. If that happens for too long you'll get the error you're seeing - `Task watchdog got triggered`. The big clue is that it happens in the `async_tcp` task.

Try rewriting your code so that the `HTTP_POST` handler sets a global variable to indicate that `execOTA()` needs to be called, rather than calling it itself. Then have `loop()` do the heavy lifting.

Something like this:

```
boolean exec_ota_flag = false;

void setup() {

...

    EspServer.on("*", HTTP_POST, [](AsyncWebServerRequest * Req){
        AsyncWebParameter* keyVal=Req->getParam(0);
        String key=keyVal->name();
        String val=keyVal->value();
        if(key=="req" && val=="execOTA"){
            exec_ota_flag = true;
            Req->send(200, "text/plain", "Updating...");
        }else{

...

void loop() {
  if(exec_ota_flag) {
      exec_ota_flag = false;
      execOTA();
  }
}
```

Also the `while` loop in execOTA needs a `delay()` call. Try something like this:

```
    while(thisClient.available()==0) {
        delay(1);
        if(millis()-timeout > 5000){
```

When you call `delay()` you give other tasks a chance to run, which will let the watchdog timer be reset.

Comment: Global variables to the rescue.  Worked perfectly.  Thank you A few of questions: 1) Why does running execOTA from the loop not also block processes on ESP?  2) It's been my understanding that delay() blocks 100% of the CPU.  Your note suggests otherwise.  How so?  Thanks again.

Comment: Good question. It does block them, but it doesn't block the TCP callback and HTTP protocol from completing by moving it to loop(), which honestly would be a different problem from the watchdog. That's why adding the delay() to it in loop() was important. delay() doesn't actually block the CPU at all. It lets other tasks on the ESP32 have a chance to run and won't resume the loop() task until the number of ms specified has gone by. It's a bit different from a real Arduino where there's nothing else going on.

Comment: RE "delay() doesn't actually block the CPU at all" -- interesting.  My (limited) understanding came in part from this link ( https://learn.adafruit.com/multi-tasking-the-arduino-part-1/ditch-the-delay ) 2nd paragraph.  Are you saying they're talking about Arduino, narrowly, but that Espressif boards function differently in this regard?

Comment: Yes. On Arduino boards - at least the earlier ones - there's no underlying OS. The software that provides the Arduino calls is the firmware. On the ESP8266 and ESP32 the Arduino software is a layer built on software provided by Espressif - FreeRTOS in the ESP32 case. That software has other functions it performs, like running the network stack. So on real  Arduino boards, there's nothing else for `delay()` to do other than wait for the delay to complete. On the Espressif boards it lets the CPU do non-preemptive multitasking so other things can run.

Comment: The call to `vTaskDelay()` that you mentioned is an example of a FreeRTOS call rather than an Arduino call. In fact, `delay()` just calls `vTaskDelay()`. You can see the implementation of the ESP32 `delay()` at https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/c2b3f2d6afc1911db1974a324782730dd642d524/cores/esp32/esp32-hal-misc.c#L144

Comment: And here's the implementation of `delay()` for Arduino AVR-based CPUs - https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/2f67c916f6ab6193c404eebe22efe901e0f9542d/cores/arduino/wiring.c#L106

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it is not clear if you are aware what the watchdog or IDLE tasks are, let alone what is triggering them. Thus I hope this helps: [FreeRTOS & IDLE Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66278271/task-watchdog-got-triggered-the-tasks-did-not-reset-the-watchdog-in-time/69065654#69065654)

Basically, No code should ever block the CPU 100% the time. But if necessary, you can, as long as you create a separate task for it, and assign the tskIDLE_PRIORITY to it. See the link for details.